# Getting cyclic dependencies error in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, autowired

I am trying to migrate our spring application to Spring boot.

I am getting an cyclic dependencies error.

Bean A  ->  Bean B ->  Bean C

In Bean C I am autowiring a Map which is defined in a XML

```
<util:map id="beanMap" map-class="java.util.HashMap">
<entry key="beanA" > <bean class="com.org.BeanA" /> </entry>
</util:map>
```

In Bean C I am autowiring

```
@Autowired
@Resource(name = "beanMap")
private Map<String, serviceInterface> beanMap;
```

This setup is working properly in Spring without boot.

But when I try to run this configuration in Spring Boot. I am facing cyclic dependencies error.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing @Autowired in Bean C.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
Tried removing @Autowired.
Still same issue.

Comment: Perhaps u can migrate your XML to Java-based configuration. Take a look at this: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13293297/spring-java-configuration-how-do-create-a-map-of-enums-to-beans-references

Comment: Blake thanks this works. But still cant understand why it was working in Spring

Comment: Spring boot philosophy is convention over configuration. It makes an assumption on several things. I guess u r migrating from a pretty old Spring version since you are still using XML. Although not really necessary, but I would eliminate XML and stick with annotations, and Java-based configuration. Have fun!