# enum returning spring beans dynamically

Tags: java, spring

Is it possible for an enum to return different spring beans for different values?

If possible, we can create an enum holding different values, and we can return different type of spring component for a different value.

I wanted to achieve something like this:

```
public enum MyFactory {
    BEAN1 {
        @Autowired
        Bean1 bean1;

       @Override
       public MyBean getMyBean() {
           return bean1;
       }
    },
    BEAN2 {
        @Autowired
        Bean1 bean2;

       @Override
       public MyBean getMyBean() {
           return bean2;
       }
    };

    public abstract MyBean getMyBean();
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: you can create `public enum Foo { BAR; public Object getBean(ApplicationContext ctx, Class value) { return ctx.getBean(value); }} ` and call it with `Foo.BAR.getBean(ctx, Target.class);` but I fail to see the point in doing so...

Comment: my expected close implementation probably is at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13293297/spring-java-configuration-how-do-create-a-map-of-enums-to-beans-references

Answer (score 0):

Java enums are designed to be constant values.
But to achieve you requirement, you should set the enum states after their creation or passing as parameter the `ApplicationContext` to the enum method or to an enum method initialization.

It defeats the enum purpose : constant values.

I think that it is make more sense to define a bean class that provides beans defined once and without way to change them.

```
@Component
public class MyEnumClass{

   @Autowired
   private Value valueA;

   @Autowired
   private Value valueB;

   public Value getValueA(){
       return valueA;
   }

   public Value getValueB(){
       return valueB;
   }
   ...

}
```

Where `Value` class is preferably not mutable.

Answer (score 0):

## Do not use enums to conditionally inject.

### Spring is more than capable of doing that on its own.

This runs somewhat counter to the whole benefit of dependency injection; so long as your components define a *common* interface between them, you can inject whichever one you want at will without the need for (self-managed) conditions.

Supposing that you had components `AComponent` and `BComponent`.  They are related and share a common-enough interface that it makes sense to codify it as an interface.  You can then define this.

```
public interface Component {
    Integer generateValue(String foo, List<Integer> bar);
}


public class AComponent implements Component {}
public class BComponent implements Component {}
```

Then, you can inject it in at will:

```
private Component component;

@Autowired
public MyService(@Qualifier("bComponent") Component component) {
    this.component = component;
}
```

Spring is perfectly capable of managing the dynamic wiring for you here.

---

Alternatively, if these components are completely *un*related to one another, then you'll have to wire them in individually anyway as opposed to dynamically selecting one based on your needs.

Comment: Hi @Makoto, I am receiving a feed which contains some JSON data and based on that, I have to call one of the several implementations. So, I thought to have an enum holding a constant value, and its related spring impl object.

Comment: You're going to want to rearchitect the approach you're wanting to take.  Enums is *not* the approach you want to use here.  This seems simple; based on a value, delegate a call to a service.  What service you use is injected in as opposed to provided by the enum.

Comment: What about going with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13293297/spring-java-configuration-how-do-create-a-map-of-enums-to-beans-references? This looks good to me.

Comment: @krmanish007:  If you want to go with that approach, that's fine.  I personally see this as an antipattern given that we already have the ability to inject dependencies as we require them.